# Does Gitlab omnibus package install ruby & git?

Tags: ruby, git, gitlab

I'm trying to install Gitlab with [omnibus package](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/) for Debian 7. Gitlab is running but it's very slow. Tail logs showed me, that unicorn process timeouts because get requests for assets timing out.

I read somewhere that I have to perform `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` but bundle command not found. Also, git command not found. Does omnibus package install ruby and git or I should do it manually? I couldn't find `ruby` or `git` in `usr/bin` or somewhere else.

Comment: Please make on question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `bundle exec rake some_task` is available for the *normal* GitLab installation, where you install all components manually.

With GitLab omnibus you can use `gitlab-rake some_task`. It will automatically use the GitLab's internal ruby installation, internal bundle etc.