# permission denied when cloning from GitLab repo hosted on an Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: git, ssh, amazon-ec2, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I can't push to/clone from a GitLab running on an Amazon EC2 instance.
Here is what I did so far

- Created a keypair on my local machine
- Created a project in Gitlab (my GitLab user has owner-permissions)
- Add my public key in the webconfig of my user in Gitlab

When I try to clone that repository via `git clone git@11.12.13.154:project-group/project.git` I get the infamous message:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

**How can I configure my EC2-instance to accept clone/push/pull requests from users who added their SSH-keys via Gitlabs web-interface?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting permission denied (public key) on gitlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427498/getting-permission-denied-public-key-on-gitlab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User ubuntu`? Usually, the user configure for a GitLab instance is `git`.

Try and modify your .ssh/config file with `User git`, and use that url:

```
git clone myhost:project-group/MyRepo.git
```

Make sure that `test.pub` (the [public key extracted from the pem file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10271238/6309)) is registered properly on the repo (or in your GitLab account, if you are the owner of that repo). If `test.pem` is the key used to access the EC2 instance, then you would need to [generate a separate public/private set of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24143976/6309) and use those instead in accessing GitLab.

After discussion below, it appears that:

- GitLab is installed on an EC2 instance with Omnibus-gilab
- Omnibus-gitlab means using `gitlab-rake some_task` (not '`rake`' directly)
- a `gitlab-rake gitlab:check` points out that the `authorized_keys` file resides in `/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- the `git` account was locked (unlocking it made the Gitlab work: `git:!:` to `git:*:` in the file `/etc/shadow`).
  This is similar to the "[Trouble Shooting Guide - SSH](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide#ssh)" section.

Comment: I used the bare repositories so far without GitLab.
How do I register that test.pem.pub and where do I get it? I only use the private key so far to authenticate via ssh / and to use the bare repositories.

Comment: @Hedge ssh means you have a private and a public key. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10271238/6309

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that but where do I get the public key of the EC2 instance. All I have is the private one.

Comment: @Hedge the pem should include both, hence my link to http://stackoverflow.com/a/10271238/6309. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/24143976/6309. The point is to generate your own private / public key and register the public one to the repo or the GitLab account. It is *not* to use the EC2 instance private key, which is just for you to access that instance, and has nothing to do with user authentication in GitLab.

Comment: Oh sorry, of course you are right about the .pem containing both.
Ok, what I did is create my own public-key (stored in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub). I saved this key in the Gitlab-configuration for my user. Created a project in Gitlab. My user with the associated public key has full permissions yet I get `permission denied` when cloning to my private computer.

Comment: @Hedge Does your config file reference the right *private* key? (with git user)

Comment: I only used to config file for the bare repositories before I installed Gitlab so I don't have to write `ssh -i ~/.ssh/test.pem ...` all the time.

To clone from Gitlab I'm trying a command in the style `git@11.12.13.14:group/project.git` so its not using the host I specified in the `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: @Hedge ok: use the config file with `myhost:project-group/MyRepo.git`. Make sure the `myhost` entry do use the right private key. Or make a new entry, if you were already using that one.

Comment: I set up a new host like this `Host newhost Hostname 11.12.13.14 user git IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` (this key is the private key matching to `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` I saved for my Gitlab user. Then I tried `git clone newhost:group/project.git` but I still get the error :(

Comment: @Hedge what a `ssh -Tvv newhost` return?

Comment: yeah, I tried it with different usernames in the config. I updated the gist using the `git` username.

Comment: @Hedge I have removed my previous comment, to not display the actual server name. So a simple `ssh -T newhost` would return what? Still permission denied. Is there a `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server side?

Comment: No, there is no such file. I was under the impression that I don't have to add my public key to the authorized_keys manually because GitLab takes care of the keys.

Comment: @Hedge yes, GitLab is supposed to managed that for you. First, do you confirm that GitLab is using the git account? (in config/gitlab.yml)

Comment: Yes, it is using the (default) git account according to `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml` What else could cause this problem?

Comment: @Hedge As long as /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys doesn't reflect properly your public key, nothing will work properly: see https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide#authorized_keys-file-is-out-of-sync if that help (that section, or the rest of the page too)

Comment: I used the Omnibus package to install Gitlab. Should I install bundler etc. to execute the rake task specified on the Wiki page or is there a simpler way to resynchronise the authorized_keys?
I looked in the file `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log`. There is a new entry that states the the key was added but the git-user doesn't even have a .ssh directory.

Comment: @Hedge Not usre actually. Unless you follow https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/363

Comment: @Hedge Wait: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27816590/6309: With GitLab omnibus you can use `gitlab-rake some_task`.

Comment: I can run the tasks as you specified. It also warns me about `You will lose any data stored in authorized_keys file.` but after typing in `yes` nothing happens. I'm starting to think that a co-worker created the user `git` manually before I took over the EC2-instance.

Comment: @Hedge I agree: as long as this isn't working properly, any ssh url won't reach Gitlab successfully.

Comment: Can I somehow delete the user and let omnibus re-create it without me having to set up the whole EC2 once again?

Comment: @Hedge That I don't know

Comment: I did a quick gitlab-rake gitlab:check and found out authorized_keys reside in `/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys`. 
Then I created a symbolic link to the .ssh folder via `sudo ln -s /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh /home/git/` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Hedge probably because the ssh daemon is configure to not look for key there (or across a symlink)

Comment: @Does `gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info` and `gitlab-rake gitlab:check`  report any issue at all?

Comment: @Hedge See also https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/538 for other suggestions to be tested.

Comment: No issues are reported with both commands. `check` does even say: Check directories and files:
 /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories: OK
 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK

Comment: I can push and pull now. I set `git:!: to git:*:` in the file `/etc/shadow`. Is this ok?

Comment: @Hedge I suppose it is OK: see https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide#ssh. I have edited the answer accordingly. (also mentioned in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5304)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience @VonC :)